# What does "She flat-tired on some junior varsity b*s*" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've watched Grace and Frankie, SE1 EP7. I liked that but I don't understand this sentence.

> She flat-tired on some junior varsity bullshit.

Frankie answered her phone while she'd been watching 'The Spelling Bee'.
Here's the part of the script for context.

> Frankie: Hi, Mike.
>
> Mike: Is this a good time?
>
> Frankie: It's always a good time to talk to you.
>
> Mike: So how is everything going?
>
> Frankie: Well, you just missed Marinda just before.
> **She flat-tired on some junior varsity bullshit.**
> Her parents are going to kill her!
>
> Mike:- And now... I'm sorry? What?
>
> Frankie: Well, you know, the spelling bee!

I think that means Marinda did something wrong. I would really appreciate it if you explain it.

Comment: Rather than simply quoting the script, it might help to explain the plot/situation. Are these people college students, teachers, what? What has Marinda done earlier in the episode? Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!!

Answer (score 1):

It means "she failed at an easy task".

"*To flat-tire on something*" probably means to fail, evoking an image of a race or progress coming to a halt.

"*[Junior varsity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_varsity_team)*" is a secondary team of younger and less experienced players at a competition.

It was an easy question that even a junior player should have gotten right but she got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Google returns just 20 hits for the collocation "**he flat-tired**", and *none* of them seem to match the cited context. It's obvious to me the intended meaning is ***flunked, failed disastrously***, but it's also obvious that *the cited usage has little or no currency*.

Comment: That's why Mike didn't understand, either. Thank you, FumbleFingers!!